# Can't add nuget to xamarin.android project with project.json

Tags: xamarin.android, nuget, nuget-package-restore, project.json, nuget-spec

I try to add the nuget package MPAndroidChart ( https://www.nuget.org/packages/MPAndroidChart/3.0.1) to my android project. But I always get the message:

```
Package MPAndroidChart 3.0.1 is not compatible with monoandroid71 (MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1) / win. Package MPAndroidChart 3.0.1 supports: net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)
```

When I create a new project with the default packages.config it works with adding the project. Is there anything I can adjust with the nuspec or my project ot fix that?

My project.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1": {}
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem with the MPAndroidChart NuGet package. The NuGet package does not have the assemblies in a specific target framework inside the lib folder.

With a project that uses a packages.config file it should allow it to be installed into any project, even those which are not compatible. It looks like project.json is more strict and disallows this.

Comment: you're right. I made a new nuspec with a subfolder for monodroid and now it works. thank you very much :)